# how to identify bug and resolve with .so file NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, .so

after adding `com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.6@aar`  for crash reporting,there are  many crashes like below

```
 Crashed: .appName|
    0  boot.oat                       0xb4aec856 bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, true>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)
    1  boot.oat                       0xb4af07e1 (Missing)
    2  boot.oat                       0xb49a03ad art::JValue art::interpreter::ExecuteGotoImpl<true, false>(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue)
    3  boot.oat                       0xb4ad26dd artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge
    4  boot.oat                       0xb4aec271 bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)
    5  boot.oat                       0xb49b0f37 art::JValue art::interpreter::ExecuteGotoImpl<false, false>(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue)
    6  boot.oat                       0xb4ad261d artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge
    7  boot.oat                       0xb4aec271 bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)
    8  boot.oat                       0xb49b0b63 art::JValue art::interpreter::ExecuteGotoImpl<false, false>(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue)
    9  boot.oat                       0xb4ad261d artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge
    10 boot.oat                       0xb4aec271 bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)
    11 boot.oat                       0xb4af0001 (Missing)
    12 boot.oat                       0xb49b0fd3 art::JValue art::interpreter::ExecuteGotoImpl<false, false>(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue)
    13 boot.oat                       0xb4ad261d artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge
    14 boot.oat                       0xb4aec271 bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)
    15 boot.oat                       0xb49b0b63 art::JValue art::interpreter::ExecuteGotoImpl<false, false>(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue)
    16 boot.oat                       0xb4ad261d artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge
    17 boot.oat                       0xb4aec271 bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)
    18 boot.oat                       0xb49b0b63 art::JValue art::interpreter::ExecuteGotoImpl<false, false>(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue)
    19 boot.oat                       0xb4ad261d artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge
    20 boot.oat                       0xb4aec271 bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)
    21 boot.oat                       0xb49b0b63 art::JValue art::interpreter::ExecuteGotoImpl<false, false>(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue)
    22 boot.oat                       0xb4ad261d artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge
    23 boot.oat                       0xb4aec271 bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)
    24 boot.oat                       0xb49b0b63 art::JValue art::interpreter::ExecuteGotoImpl<false, false>(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue)
    25 boot.oat                       0xb4ad261d artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge
    26 boot.oat                       0xb4aec271 bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)
    27 boot.oat                       0xb49b0b63 art::JValue art::interpreter::ExecuteGotoImpl<false, false>(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue)
    28 boot.oat                       0xb4ad261d artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge
    29 boot.oat                       0xb4aec271 bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)
    30 boot.oat                       0xb49b0b63 art::JValue art::interpreter::ExecuteGotoImpl<false, false>(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue)
    31 boot.oat                       0xb4ad261d artInterpreterToInterpreterBridge
    32 boot.oat                       0xb4aec271 bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)
    33 boot.oat                       0xb4af0001 (Missing)
    34 boot.oat                       0xb49b0fd3 art::JValue art::interpreter::ExecuteGotoImpl<false, false>(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue)
    35 boot.oat                       0xb4ad23f5 art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*)
    36 boot.oat                       0xb4cd865b artQuickToInterpreterBridge
    37 boot.oat                       0xb49daf43 (Missing)
    38 boot.oat                       0x735382cb (Missing)
```

above crash are reported with devices like Hisense,LGE,Vitsmo,Bmobile and LAVA with same android VERSION 6 or 6.0.1
Second one

```
Crashed: .appName|
0  libffmpeg.so                   0x8ff8c292 (Missing)
```

above crash are reported with devices like Samsung,ACT,LGE,Vitsmo,ASUS and LAVA

i have many .so file in app listed below
[image]

how can I understand this crash, it's because of which SDK or code and how to resolve it?

Comment: Your app includes **libffmpeg.so**, doesn't it? Is this a *shared library*, or an [executable in disguise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15099666/192373)?

Comment: Your app includes libffmpeg.so, doesn't it? yes i have updated the question

Comment: I have seen similar crashes, but very few, and there was no way to reproduce them. Does the crash happen *'reliably'* in your case? I mean, with Crashlytics you can analyze if this happens again and again on the same device, or once in a while. Does it happen for a significant percent of your users on problematic devices?

Comment: you can check it from here http://crashes.to/s/8bdbc7aad90 ,it's reported for 17 user within last 24 hour i have just release updated yesterday

Comment: If I understand correctly, this happens quite often on test devices. You should look into the system logs to understand the details.

Comment: I have tried a number of times but there are no logs.

Comment: @AlexCohn after updating mapping file using `gradlew crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease` i have seen some more details  http://crashes.to/s/2774a03fac6  , http://crashes.to/s/0faf4c921ea can you please help me to identify more about it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160087/discussion-between-alex-cohn-and-om-infowave-developers).