# Build NDK exectuable with CMAKE : no dynamic library found error

Tags: gradle, cmake, android-ndk

What i want is to build a native binary with NDK. There are couples shared lib also been build. 
The APK structure look like this:

```
/data/data/mypackage/files/my_binary
/data/data/mypackage/lib/liba.so
/data/data/mypackage/lib/libb.so
```

When the binary is been executed,error like `CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE: could not load library "liba.so" needed by "./mybinay"; caused by library liba.so not found` been throw out. It's working fine after setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/data/data/mypackage/lib`.

My question is how to make it work without setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in CMAKE file or Gradel?

Cmake file.

```
add_library(a, src/a.cc)
add_library(b, src/b.cc)
add_executable(mybinary src/mybinary.cc)
target_link_libraries(a log)
target_link_libraries(mybinary a android log b)
```

Gradle file.

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        cppFlags "-std=c++14 -frtti -fexceptions"
        targets 'mybinary','a','b'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runtime scenario is not related to CMake or gradle. You don't need **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** to *build* the executable.

I prefer to pack the executable into `libs/` of the APK, next to **liba.so** and **libb.so**. The trick is to rename **my_binary** to something Ike **libmy_binary.so** (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15099666/192373).

So, this would mean that now **CMakeLists.txt** can look as follows:

```
add_library(a, src/a.cc)
add_library(b, src/b.cc)
add_executable(mybinary src/mybinary.cc)
target_link_libraries(a log)
target_link_libraries(lib.mybinary.so a android log b)
```

And setting **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** is trivial:

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
        getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir + "/lib.mybinary.so", 
        new String[]{"LD_LIBRARY_PATH="+ getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir});
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: what i wanted is to build executable which has some shared libraries to be run without setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH in runtime.  Copying executable to the same directory as .so file doesn't help. It's still complaining about .so file not found. I guess there are some ways to add /data/data/mypackage/lib/ into system LD_LIBRARY_PATH. i don't fully understand your trick about renaming executable file.   Do you mean add_library instead of add_executable for my_binary?

Comment: 1. No, there is no trick to automatically have LD_LIBRARY_PATH updated.

Comment: 2. No, we build executable. We only change the name. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: having some strange error when using the trick way. Error is pointed to that line 'target_link_libraries(lib.mybinary.so...).   Anyway, setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH code is really helpful.  thanks

Comment: UPDATE: regarding the error i mentioned in prior comment, it's my mistake to forget change mybinary to lib.mybinary.so in line add_executable().  It actually works and this exe file packed into apk.  thanks!