# How to embed an exe in a android maui app?

Tags: android, maui

I have a class library that has a exe embedded in it and works fine on windows when used in .net maui (net 8) but when trying to deploy to android using the emulator the exe is not copied across (Build Action is Content and is set to Copy Always).

I also tried embedding it as a resource and then copying it from the resource at runtime using the following code:

```
fullPathToHolochainExe = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "HolochainBinaries/beta/holochain.exe");

if (!File.Exists(fullPathToHolochainExe))
{
    using (FileStream fsDst = new FileStream(fullPathToHolochainExe, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        byte[] bytes = Resources.holochain;
        fsDst.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
}
```

This again works fine on Windows but for Android it says it does not have write permission.

There must be a way to embed an exe in a maui android app somehow?

Any help would be really appreciated.

My 2nd question is, is it possible to use PowerShell for the maui app running on android? We need to pipe in a string to the exe, which powershell supports. Unless because its linux that android is using, it would use bash internally so the pipe should work without having to resort to powershell (Like you are force to on windows)?

Many thanks,
David.

Comment: Assuming you _do_ manage to embed the EXE, you're not going to be able to launch an EXE file (that is, a Windows executable) on Android, which is Linux-based.  For PowerShell...maybe.  It _does_ support Linux, not sure about Android.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, yes I am aware of that, they have linux binaries I was intending to use instead of the exe but still need to find a way to embed them... any ideas? :) Thanks.

Comment: With the rather large caveats that 1) I know nothing at all about Maui, and 2) I haven't tried this myself and I'm not sure if the same technique still works on current versions of Android, maybe give [the solution in this question a try](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15093663/208273) if that's something that's possible in Maui.  I can't speak to whether you can or how you exactly would go about doing it from the .NET code, though.